# How can detect number of joystick connected with my mac using c++?

Tags: c++, macos, joystick

I am stuck on a problem: in my software I have to code for finding the number of joysticks connected to my Mac using C++... I have no idea about that...

Any sample code or suggestion will very much helpful for me.

Comment: basically its a compiler for a software which will run some files and for some files i have to control joystick to operate the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SDL library, it should work on Mac and PC as well. [Documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guideinput.html)

Number of joysticks can be determined with just one function call:

```
int n = SDL_NumJoysticks();
```